# Sliding Menu doesn't Close with its original Width

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, slidingmenu

I am working in android project in which I have implemented Sliding Menu using Sliding menu library with ActionbarSherlock library. All is working good. But what I am facing: initially my sliding menu is set to the width of 50 when the app starts. When I click on menu instead of opening in full screen mode it closes and after clicking again on menu it opens in full screen. This is my first issue.

Second thing is that when I close the sliding menu it didn't close to its fixed original width which was set by me to 50, as I have described in my question above. So here I'm facing these two issue and have tried a lot but no result.

This is my screenshot.

[image]

Here my code also.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
        ab.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.header_img);
        Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.header_bg);
        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(d);

        menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
        menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);

        menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
        // menu.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
        // menu.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
        // menu.setAboveOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset_above);
        menu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
        // int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
        // int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
        menu.setBehindWidth(50);

        menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
        menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_WINDOW);
        menu.setMenu(R.layout.menu);
        menu.setSlidingEnabled(true);
        menu.setOnClosedListener(new OnClosedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClosed() {
                Log.e("", "onClosed");
                menu.setBehindWidth(200);
            }
        });

        menu.showMenu();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        menu.toggle();
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```